# Attach the bar's bottom to a location in 3D Cesium

Tags: javascript, mapping, cesium

I have the code below on web site cesiumjs.

Is there any way that I can fix the bar's bottom at the location (37.786805,-122.45475) on the Earth's surface?  The bar here looks like its bottom moves to different location when user changes the view point with mouse. I would like its bottom is fixed at the location showed in the picture:

[image]

[Link to cesiumjs.org and code](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/#c=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)

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var data = {"data": [{'cell': 'CCL00001', 'lat': 37.7868056, 'lng': -122.45475,
                        'Instagram': 4875.9842197545295,
                        'Twitter': 12549.83683767872,
                        'Facebook': 14216.538636363637,
                        'Netflix': 134291.15366972476,
                        'Google': 172588.27142857143,
                        'Other': 202959.5143769968
                    },
                    {'cell': 'CCL00005', 'lat': 37.7298061, 'lng': -122.4738231,
                        'Instagram': 2501.451010587103,
                        'Twitter': 14455.444364809175,
                        'Facebook': 120458.94586894587,
                        'Netflix': 114198.37105171815,
                        'Google': 167619.12919343327,
                        'Other': 119965.0
                    }

                ]};
            var colors = {
                /*'Instagram': Cesium.Color.WHITE, //'brown',
                'Twitter': Cesium.Color.GREEN, //'yellow',
                'Facebook': Cesium.Color.YELLOW, //'red',
                'Netflix': Cesium.Color.BLUEVIOLET,*/
                'Google': Cesium.Color.BLUE, //'blue',
                'Other': Cesium.Color.RED//'black'
            };
            for (var i =0; i<1; i++) {
                console.log(i);
                console.log()
                var alt = -20000;
                for (var cp in colors) {
                    console.log(cp);
                    var height = data.data[i][cp]/10;
                    console.log("height: " + height)
                    alt += height ;
                    console.log("alt: " +alt);
                    var cell = data.data[i];
                    console.log(cell.lat);

                    var blueBox = viewer.entities.add({
                        name: cp,
                        position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(cell.lng, cell.lat, alt),
                        box: {
                            dimensions: new Cesium.Cartesian3(4000/5.0, 3000.0/5, height),
                            material: colors[cp]
                        }
                    });
                }
            }


            /*var outlineOnly = viewer.entities.add({
             name : 'Yellow box outline',
             position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-100.0, 40.0, 300000.0),
             box : {
             dimensions : new Cesium.Cartesian3(400000.0, 300000.0, 500000.0),
             fill : false,
             outline : true,
             outlineColor : Cesium.Color.YELLOW
             }
             });*/

            viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bar's bottom isn't moving.  You're seeing the bar sticking down below the surface of the Earth.  Cesium won't chop off the bar at height zero by default, unless you set this:

```
viewer.scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;
```

If you set that though, you'll lose visibility of the underground portion of the bar.  You may want to move the whole thing higher, so you can see the full height of the bar.